# Asserting complex spock interaction

Tags: unit-testing, spock

Have really been struggling trying to get this spock test working.

The code under test:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

public class UserConsole {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserConsole.class);

    public boolean getConfirmationFromUser() {
        writeLine("USER RESPONSE REQUIRED: yes/no");
        while(true) {
            final String userResponse = readLine();
            if(userResponse.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                return true;
            } else if(userResponse.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                return false;
            }
            writeLine("Invalid input received '" + userResponse + "'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'");
        }
    }

    public String readLine() {
        return System.console().readLine();
    }

    public void writeLine(final String text){
        LOG.info(text);
    }
}
```

And my test code:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class UserConsoleTest extends Specification {
    def "test getConfirmationFromUser"() {
        given:
        final UserConsole userConsole = Spy(UserConsole)

        when:
        boolean result = userConsole.getConfirmationFromUser();

        then:
        1 * userConsole.writeLine("USER RESPONSE REQUIRED: yes/no")
        1 * userConsole.readLine() >> "blah!"
        1 * userConsole.writeLine("Invalid input received 'blah!'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'")
        1 * userConsole.readLine() >> "still blah!"
        1 * userConsole.writeLine("Invalid input received 'still blah!'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'")
        1 * userConsole.readLine() >> "yes"
        assert result == true
    }
}
```

The idea of the test is to feed the console two bad responses ("blah!" and "still blah!", followed by a valid response ("yes")

However I cannot get spock to verify the interactions.  Am constantly seeing assertion failures such as this:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * userConsole.writeLine("Invalid input received 'blah!'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'")   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

3 * userConsole.invokeMethod('readLine', [])
1 * userConsole.getConfirmationFromUser()

Too few invocations for:

1 * userConsole.writeLine("Invalid input received 'still blah!'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'")   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

3 * userConsole.invokeMethod('readLine', [])
1 * userConsole.getConfirmationFromUser()


    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:76)
    at com.anz.axle.tooling.installer.UserConsoleTest.test GetConfirmationFromUser user initially enters invalid value(UserConsoleTest.groovy:39)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order your interaction mocks then you actually need separate `then` blocks. If they are all in the same block, then there is no asserted order.

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class UserConsoleTest extends Specification {
  def "test getConfirmationFromUser"() {
    given:
      final UserConsole userConsole = Spy(UserConsole)

    when:
      boolean result = userConsole.getConfirmationFromUser();

    then:
      1 * userConsole.writeLine("USER RESPONSE REQUIRED: yes/no")
      1 * userConsole.readLine() >> "blah!"
    then:
      1 * userConsole.writeLine("Invalid input received 'blah!'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'")
      1 * userConsole.readLine() >> "still blah!"
    then:
      1 * userConsole.writeLine("Invalid input received 'still blah!'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'")
      1 * userConsole.readLine() >> "yes"
    then:
      assert result == true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the writeLine method where you should (according to your test):

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

public class UserConsole {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserConsole.class);

    public boolean getConfirmationFromUser() {
        writeLine("USER RESPONSE REQUIRED: yes/no");
        while(true) {
            final String userResponse = readLine();
            if(userResponse.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                return true;
            } else if(userResponse.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                return false;
            }
            writeLine("Invalid input received '" + userResponse + "'.  Legal values are: 'yes' or 'no'");
        }
    }

    public String readLine() {
        return System.console().readLine();
    }

    public void writeLine(final String text){
        LOG.info(text);
    }
}
```

Let me know if that makes the trick.

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely correct.  Thanks very much, that was a stupid bug.  I'm going to clean up the question with your fix.  the other answer above actually nailed how the spock should look, so will clean up the question, and leave with the other answer to help others out with similar spock problems.